# Prove that $f$ is convex if, and only if, $f(x)\geq f(y) + f'(y)(x-y)$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Prove that $f:I\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, a differentiable fuction, is convex if, and only if, $f(x)\geq f(y) + f'(y)(x-y)$

Attempt: If I have $f(x)\geq f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)$

Defining $a=(1−t)x+ty$, with $t\in[0,1]$, it's not difficult to prove $f(a)\leq(1−t)f(x)+tf(y)$, by doing $t=\frac{a−x}{y−x}$ and $1−t=\frac{y−a}{y−x}$

together with the hypothesis: $f(x)\geq f(a)+f'(a)(x−a)$ and $f(y)\geq f(a)+f'(a)(y−a)$

But I'm having a hard time proving the other half. If $f$ is convex: $f((1−t)x+ty)\leq(1−t)f(x)+tf(y)$.
How do I get $f(x)\geq f(y) + f'(y)(x-y)$?

Comment: $\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} = f'(c)$ for some $c \in (x, y)$, so it suffices to prove that $f'(x)$ is increasing.

Comment: To this end, we need only prove that, for $x < t < y$, we have $$\frac{f(t) - f(x)}{t - x} \le \frac{f(y) - f(t)}{y - t}.$$ Try to prove this directly.

Comment: Are there additional assumptions, such as $f$ is differentiable?  Otherwise, you can have convex functions such as $|x|$ which are not differentiable.

Comment: @DanielSchepler True, but I figured that $C^1$ functions were implicitly required by OP. (One can prove that a convex function must *always* be $C^0$.)

Comment: @schepler, it is differentible, I forgot to add that.

Comment: I thought a convex function could potentially have discontinuities at endpoints of the interval.  e.g. $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x = 1 \vee x = -1; \\ 0, & -1 < x < 1. \end{cases}$$

Comment: @DanielSchepler It's guaranteed if the interval of definition is open; otherwise it can trivially fail, like here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: write
$$f(x)\ge\frac{(t-1)f(y)+f(tx+(1-t)y)}{t}$$
and let $t\to0$.

Comment: you mean $f(y) \geq$... right?

Comment: Yes, I had originally made an error - fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

This is very well-known theorem, and you can find its traditional proof in any convex optimization book. But Here I see more arguments. It seems to me your function is differentiable! So I came up another simpler proof:

Define $g:[0,1] \to R$ with $g(t) =t f (x) + (1-t)f(y) - f(x+t (y-x))  $ then $g$ is differentiable $g(t) \ge 0 \quad \forall t \in [0,1]$ and $g(0) = 0$  therefore $ g'(0) = 0.$   Then...   (Just calculate $g'(0)$).

Comment: $g(t) \leq 0$ isn't it?